# Travis-ci symfony app/console: Permission denied

Tags: php, symfony, testing, travis-ci

I have .travis.yml and when travis start for building I have error and dont know why this is:

```
language: php
php:
- "5.5.9"
env:
- SYMFONY_VERSION=2.6.*
before_script:
# Copy skeleton parameters file
- cp app/config/parameters.yml.dist app/config/parameters.yml
# Install packages
- sudo apt-get update > /dev/null
- sudo apt-get install -y --force-yes apache2 libapache2-mod-php5  php5-curl php5-mysql php5-intl
# Create VirtualHost
- sudo sed -i -e "s,/var/www,$(pwd)/web,g" /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
- sudo sed -i -e "/DocumentRoot/i\ServerName mychristmas.local" /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
- echo "127.0.0.1 mychristmas.local" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
- sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
# Update php.ini
- echo 'display_errors = On' >> ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/php.ini
 - echo 'html_errors = On' >> ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/php.ini
 - echo 'short_open_tag = Off' >> ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/php.ini
 - echo 'date.timezone = "Europe/Kiev"' >> ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/php.ini
 # Update composer
 - composer self-update
 - composer install --dev --prefer-dist
 # Make symfony2 preparation steps
 - mkdir -p web/upload/media
 - app/console do:da:cr -e=test > /dev/null
 - app/console do:sc:cr -e=test > /dev/null
 - php app/console assets:install --symlink
 - php app/console assetic:dump
 - sudo chmod -R 777 app/cache app/logs
 - app/console --env=test cache:warmup
 - sudo chmod -R 777 app/cache app/logs
 # Check
 #- php app/check.php
 script:
 - phpunit -c app/
```

and in travis I have error

```
/home/travis/build.sh: line 41: app/console: Permission denied

The command "app/console do:da:cr -e=test > /dev/null" failed and exited with 126 during .
```

Why for app/console permisin denied ?? I am not understand and what to do for fix this?

Comment: Try running it with `php`, like `php app/console ...`

Comment: ... or `chmod +x app/console`

Comment: How? Can you add an answer explaining it and showing that your question is answered please?